# Is jaotc for Java Ahead of Time Compilation available for armv7 (32bit)

Tags: java, armv7, jaotc

My slow BlackBox device with a single armv7 CPU uses Java 14. The JRE is custom built (not by me) but is missing `jaotc` which is unfortunate because I really hoped to try it for this device.

I thought `jaotc` was now available for all environments, or does it not include 32bit such as *armv7*, if not currently available any chance that it will become available in a later version of Java?

Comment: Possibly related: [*GraalVM as JIT compiler for ARM JRE*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705341/graalvm-as-jit-compiler-for-arm-jre)